# Hardware issue: my PC needs rest sometimes

Tags: shutdown

It is very surprising but true thet when i shutdown my PC but doesnt unplug the power cabel (even if i had switched off) then i my PC doesnt get started next time. I need to unplug power cable for 2 Hrs then only i can start it.

I had changed my house
I had changed motherboard, CPU & RAM

I am not able to identify the issue. And how can i resolve it.

Please suggest.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/198862/motherboard-wont-power-on-until-it-rests-for-10min-with-no-power-plugged-in-o-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tested your power supply? Buy a power supply tester (good to have one in general anyway) and make sure your power supply is operating correctly.

Comment: Sure does sound power supply-like.

Comment: ya ofcourse i had. even some of my friends who is having harware knowledge, checked it. But no solution

Comment: Are you certain there is nothing about the way the board is installed in the case that is causing it to short out? This just screams of a power related issue, I'd check the grounding and make sure everything is good.

Comment: This was mother board problem only.